# With Django Websockets, how can I subscribe the current user to a new group from views.py

Tags: django, django-channels, consumer

In Django, I have models.py with Collection and Members as a relationship to them:

```
# models.py
class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)


class Member(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="account_set", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I have a websocket for notifying members whenever we have changes in a collection that the user is member of. For that, I have MainConsumer, shown below.

```
# consumers.py

class MainConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        user_id = self.scope['user_id']
        collection_ids = Member.objects.filter(account_id=user_id).values_list("collection_id", flat=True)

        for collection_id in collection_ids:
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(f'collection_ws_{collection_id}' , self.channel_name)
        
        self.accept()
```

Works like a charm. I can comunicate perfectly. Question is the following:

If I create a new collection, I need somehow to tell my MainConsumer that the requested user should now receive notifications from this new collection as well.

```
# views.py
class CollectionCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    collection = Collection.objects.create(name=request.data['name'])

    # Create a member as admin
    member = Member.objects.create(
        collection=collection,
        account=request.user,
    )

    ** -- Here I want to 'subscribe' the current user to this new collection as well, but I cant figure out how... -- **


    return JsonResponse({"payload": CollectionSerializer(collection, many=False).data
    }, status=200)
```

Worth mentioning that I could "reload" my websocket in the frontend and it works, but it seems a bit weird to do it like that.
I have seen some things like this on SO and I believe this is the way to go, but I could not make it work:

```
        async_to_sync(get_channel_layer().group_add)(f'collection_ws_{collection.id}', channel_name) # but I do not even have access to channel_name
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but maybe you can get channel_name with this : `channel_name = async_to_sync(get_channel_layer().new_channel)`

Comment: OK I found new_channel on the docs at https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/channel_layer_spec.html
I will try to work it out and if it works I let you know.